# how do you trigger an event on phaser.js by clicking anywhere js

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

In a phaser.js game, (flappy bird), I want the bird to "flap" every time anywhere is clicked. The tutorial I am following just shows how to initiate when the space bar is pressed. How can I make it happen by clicking anywhere?

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(400, 490, Phaser.auto, 'game_div');
var main_state = {
    preload: function () {
        this.game.stage.backgroundColor = '#71c5cf';
        this.game.load.image('bird', '../img/bird.png');
    },
    create: function () {
        this.game.load.image('bird')
    },
    update: function () {

    }
}
```

EDIT:
I am using this with phonegap, so would that syntax effect the answer?

Answer (score 0):

That you use phaser js doesnt mean that you cannot use standard js:

```
window.addEventListener("click",function(event){
  main_state.flap();
  event.stopPropagation();//prevent phaser detection
},false);


var main_state = { 
     game = new Phaser.Game(400, 490, Phaser.auto, 'game_div'),
     preload: function () { this.game.stage.backgroundColor = '#71c5cf'; this.game.load.image('bird', '../img/bird.png'); },
     create: function () { this.game.load.image('bird') }, 
     update: function () { },
     flap:function(){//your flap code
     }
     };
```

Just add a flap function in your main_state object. Also *this.game* doesnt work. Use *game* instead

Comment: thanks for telling me about _this.game_. I didn't really find out how old my tutorial was! :)I tried to copy and paste that code into a function _flap_. Where does this go?

Comment: @lincoln: not old, wrong! this is main_state in this case. While game is part of the window object

Comment: @lincoln : outside of everything. It than calls main_state.flap(); (may learn basic js before trying to program flappy bird...)

Comment: @lincoln updated, to make it easier for you to understand

Comment: That's what I did, and it still didn't work. I put it outside of everything and I got a syntax error! `Expected ";"` on the first line of your code, then `expected expression` on the last.

Comment: google chrome. The syntax error is being shown in WebMatrix, though. Maybe use a more widely recognized syntax?